# Oracle Homework - SQL Statement error - Again

Tags: sql

I am not sure why I am getting this error, this code is fairly straight forward. The error is:

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

The code is:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS "EMPLOYEES"
FROM F_STAFFS
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE 'D%'
AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%a%' AND '%e%';
```

I am trying to display the first and last name in a column titled "EMPLOYEES" where the last name starts with "D" and the last name contains the letters "a" and "e".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS "EMPLOYEES"
FROM F_STAFFS
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE 'D%'
AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%a%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%e%';
```

But this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME AS "EMPLOYEES"
FROM F_STAFFS
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE 'D%a%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%e%';
```

Answer (score 0):

`'%e%'` is not a valid logical expression.

what you need is:

```
AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%a%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%e%';
```